# The 'c' in the spelling of $\operatorname{arsinh}(x)$ vs $\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)$.

Tags: notation, hyperbolic-functions

Where is the 'c' in the spelling of the inverse hyperbolic function of sine? Isn't it just a hyperbolic version of $\operatorname{arcsin}(x)$? That is, why is it written $\operatorname{arsinh}(x)$ and not $\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)$?

The same question applies to the other functions as well.

Comment: arc=Arcus ($\approx$ circle) , ar=area . Never seen "arcsinh" (it doesn't make sense).

Comment: Another notation is asinh ... but user is right.  The inverse hyperbolic sine has nothing to do with arc-length, so arcsinh is nonsense.

Comment: @user90369, you should post as an answer and maybe expand a little

Comment: @MarkS.: Sorry, I don't want to waste more time on it. It's a question of ChubbyChoc and I hope he has now the answer which he has looked for.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood your question :D. I thought you were asking why a constant can be added to the inverse function.

Comment: I don't know if what I am saying is useful, but I am Italian and we only use $\arcsin$ and we call it "arcoseno" (arcsine); I have never heard about $\text{arsin}$.

Comment: @Lorenzo, not "arsin", "arsinh". According to the wikipedia discussion of "[funzioni iperboliche inverse](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzioni_iperboliche#Funzioni_iperboliche_inverse)", it seems this may be "settsinh" in Italian, rather than "arsinh".

Comment: I have never heard "settsinh" before now. I was sure that both arcsine and the hyperbolic equivalent had "arc" in their abbreviation

Comment: @Lorenzo [the notazione section](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzioni_iperboliche#Notazioni) of the same article suggests that maybe all three of "arcsinh" "arsinh" and "settsinh" are in use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [user90369](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/332823/user90369) pointed out, the "arc" in "$\arcsin$" comes from [Latin arcus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arcus#Latin), which is directly related to the English word "arc". This makes sense because functions like $\arcsin$ give you the length of the corresponding arc of the unit circle (which also happens to be *twice* the area of the corresponding sector).

In contrast, "ar" is short for "area", since the hyperbolic functions are related to [areas bounded by the unit hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#/media/File:Hyperbolic_functions-2.svg). Specifically, $\mathrm{arsinh}$ gives you twice the area of the corresponding sector and isn't related to the arclength of the piece of the hyperbola in a simple way.

[Wikipedia confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Notation) this story with references to *Mathematics: From the Birth of Numbers*, *Oxford Users' Guide to Mathematics*, and *Handbook of Mathematics*.

Comment: Nice answer. (+1) :-)

Comment: We coukd relate the hyperbolic sector to an arc length if we apply the non-Euclidean (but well-known to physicists) metric $ds^2=dy^2-dx^2$. But yes, area is a more natural geometric characteristic, and Conway and Guy even favor dropping the "c" from "arsin" and related inverse trig functions.