Why don't we use arsinh and arsin for the inverse sinh and sin functions respectively?
I understand that we write arsinh rather than arcsinh for the inverse of $\sinh$ as unlike for the circular trig functions $\sinh^{-1}$ doesn't correspond to the arc length of the unit hyperbola.
However both arsinh and $\arcsin$ correspond to the area under unit circle/hyperbola so why don't we just use arsinh and arsin for consistency?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682208/the-c-in-the-spelling-of-operatornamearsinhx-vs-operatornamearcsinh

Geometrically, $\sin$ is usually defined in terms of arc length, whereas $\sinh$ is defined using areas. So it doesn't seem too surprising to me that we use $\arcsin x$ (i.e. the arc whose sine is $x$), and $\operatorname{arsinh} y$ (i.e. twice the area of the sector cut out by the origin, the vertex of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$, and the point on the hyperbola with vertical coordinate $y$). Some people do define $\sin$ geometrically in terms of areas, but I would say that this is a less common (at least in school textbooks).

Conway and Guy do recommend the nomenclature suggested by the OP, I've seen it in their Book of Numbers.
In fact, inverse hyperbolic functions can be matched to arc lengths on the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ by using a specially designed metric. It may look strange, but it actually plays a major role in the physical world.
